# Invalid scope when getting access token to EWS on Office365

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365, exchangewebservices

I am trying to request an access token for EWS with a regular @outlook.com Office 365 account. Using EWS with Basic Auth is working without problems.

I am requesting the scope

`https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All`

from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common`.

With an account from our organization this token is granted and access is possible. But with the @outlook.com account it givers me the error

`The provided resource value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid`

Where is the difference between an organization Office 365 Account and @outlook.com account. And why are the valid scopes different?

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The scope is "https://outlook.office.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All".

Try this code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth